# How to Get My Header Set Up Using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a complete noob when it comes to using bootstrap, or any HTML. I made a simple banner using photoshop and a simple nav-bar for my high school robotics team, but I am having trouble comprehending bootstrap's grid system. For some reason, my navbar is cutting off my banner. I want the banner below the navbar, how would I do this using bootstrap?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Robotics Team 3774 Home</title>

<!-- Link to stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index1.css">


<!-- Mobile Scaling -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

<!-- Navbar -->

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Team 3774</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="height: 0.866667px;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Team Bio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Robot</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Coach</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Outreach</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Banner -->
<div class="banner">
    <img src="Banner.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
</div>




</body>
```

Comment: Site is www.robotichive3774.com  if you want to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't really have a banner element, and the grid system isn't necessarily related to placing an item like that into your page. If you want a banner that spans the page like the navbar does, then you probably want to look at their [Jumbotron](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron) element. All you really have to do is replace your "banner" class with a "jumbotron" like so:

```
<!-- Banner -->
<div class="jumbotron">
    <img src="Banner.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Reponsive image" />
</div>
```

Then you just need to add a little custom styling to hide the gray background and have your banner image take up the width of the screen:

```
.jumbotron {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
}
```

That should do it. I had to edit my answer once I saw that you had posted the link to your website.

**Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nzhhk5sr/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

include your banner inside the container tag

```
<head>

<title>Robotics Team 3774 Home</title>

<!-- Link to stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index1.css">


<!-- Mobile Scaling -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

<!-- Navbar -->

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Team 3774</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="height: 0.866667px;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Team Bio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Robot</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Coach</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Outreach</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
   <!-- Banner -->
<div class="banner">
    <img src="Banner.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following line to your CSS:

```
body
{
    padding-top:50px;
}
```

And you should be good to go.

This is generally done in Bootstrap when `navbar-fixed-top` is used.